# is it possible to solve Cross-Origin Resource Sharing issue from client side?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

i am making a application by using REST API. the api provide me data but browser block for CORS policy. is it possible solve the issue from client side. or need to work at serve. i have try some nodejs package like cors-anywhere but still having issue

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to solve for good, because it is handled by server to control the origin request (The origin of the request(client) and the server must be in the same origin). But while you are developing you can use cors chrome extension, it will allow you to make the requests.

[Chome extension.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

Hope it helps.